# Why does Puppet keep installing a package even if it is already installed?

Tags: linux, installation, rpm, puppet

I use the package `install` attribute to ensure that given package `X` is installed.

However, even though the package is installed, `puppet` tries to install it over again and of course exits with an exception ("X already installed"). It does not happen when the package name matches a service name. I use local RPM and an RPM provider.

How do I avoid that exception?

---

I also implemented a workaround: if I succeed with the RPM installation, I create a file called `/X_DONE`. Then I install the dependencies based on that file, not the package.

What is the proper way to deal with that?

EDIT:
Failing manifest:

```
 file {"$tmp_dir/$php_pdo":
   ensure => present,
   source => "puppet:///files/services/$php_pdo"
 }

 package {"php_pdo":
   require => File["$tmp_dir/$php_pdo"],
   ensure => installed,
   provider => rpm,
   source => "$tmp_dir/$php_pdo"
 }
```

and exception:

```
err: /Stage[main]/Apache-php/Package[php_pdo]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/bin/rpm -i --oldpackage /tmp/puppet/php-pdo-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64.rpm' returned 1:     package php-pdo-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 is already installed
```

Comment: If you can post the classes/manifests that you are using it would be easier to diagnose.

Comment: This is old, but... Maintaining in /tmp a copy of whatever packages you need installed is probably not ideal either, as this will result in a loop where a cleaning of /tmp (on reboot or maybe nightly) will remove the rpm, and puppet will copy it back down.  And you'll be wasting space in /tmp on an RPM which is already installed.  Probably better to set up a yum repo, or (especially with an "installed" ensure as opposed to "latest") install from a http url.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You refer to the package by the name "php_pdo", but Puppet sees the package as "php-pdo" (dash, not underscore).  Every time it checks to see of php_pdo is installed, it finds out that it is not.  Unfortunately it doesn't matter how many times you install php-pdo, it will never be php_pdo.

To resolve the issue, change the line:

```
package {"php_pdo":
```

to be:

```
package {"php-pdo":
```

Comment: wow, so $names are so 'heavy'. Thanks a lot, it puts light in my system ;)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I don't think above is a correct answer.

Package name should be found according to its package manager.

for ubuntu

```
root@Web2:~# dpkg --get-selections | grep php
php-pdo install
```

package name would be `php-pdo`

for centos

```
[root@centos 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64-x86_64]# rpm -qa | grep php
```

we need to omit the version for rpm according to this reference
http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Strict_RPM_Package_Version_Management